# how to save screen share stream in webRTC app

Tags: javascript, asp.net, webrtc

I have a video application written in asp.net and c# with webRTC in JS.
some outsource wrote it for me a while ago (can't reach him any more) the application is working really good, except for one problem.
this video application was written for screen sharing use, and it uses some chrome extension for the screen sharing that also work good. the problem is that as soon as you go back from the screen sharing to the webcam stream, you cannot go back to the screen sharing stream. and it look like the programmer wrote this like this.
i tried turning on the extension again but it sends me an error. my question is, is there a way i can save the screen sharing stream and change the video feed with out touching the extension? 
this is the js code for webrtc:
main problem in getfeed in the third 'if'

```
     getFeed = function (shareScreen, username, userType, reinit, cb) {
         if (shareScreen) {
             $("#screen-share").attr("disabled", "disabled");
             $("#video-share").removeAttr("disabled");

           //  getUserMedia(session, onSuccess, onError);
             if (webrtcDetectedBrowser == "chrome") {
                 DetectRTC.screen.isChromeExtensionAvailable(function (isAvaliabe) {
                     if (isInScreenSharing) {
                         return;
                     }
                     if (isAvaliabe) {
                         isInScreenSharing = true;
                         captureUserMedia(onSuccess);

                     } else {
                         alertify.confirm("Screen sharing extension is not installed," +
                             " do you wish to install it now?",
                             function(e) {
                                 if (e) {

    window.open("https://chrome.google.com/webstore/detail/screen-capturing- 
    for-micr/hmppjaalobpkbpneompfdpfilcmfhfik", "_blank");
                                     alertify.alert("Click Ok to reload page 
    after installing extension ", function () {
                                         location.href = location.href;
                                     });
                                 }
                             });
                     }
                 });

             } else {
                 isInScreenSharing = false;
                 getScreenId(function (error, sourceId, screen_constraints) {
                     screen_constraints.video = _showWebCam;
                     screen_constraints.audio = _showWebCam;
                     getUserMedia(screen_constraints, onSuccess, onError);
                 });
             }


         } else {
             $("#video-share").attr("disabled", "disabled");
             $("#screen-share").removeAttr("disabled");

             getUserMedia(
             {
                 // Permissions to request
                 video: _showWebCam,
                 audio: _showWebCam
             }, onSuccess, onError);
         }

         function onSuccess(stream) { // succcess callback gives us a media stream
             $('.instructions').hide();
             if (reinit) {

                 if (screenStream) {
                     screenStream.getTracks().forEach(function (e) {
                         e.stop();
                     });
                     screenStream = null;
                 }
                 // Store off the stream reference so we can share it later
                 _mediaStream = stream;
                 if (webrtcDetectedBrowser == "chrome") {
                     if (shareScreen) {
                         //get the audio track from video stream and put it in screeen stream

                         var audioTrack = videoStream.getAudioTracks()[0];
                         var screenAudio = stream.getAudioTracks()[0];
                         if (screenAudio) {
                             _mediaStream.removeTrack(screenAudio)

                         }
                         _mediaStream.addTrack(audioTrack)
                         screenStream = _mediaStream;


                     } else {
                         videoStream = stream;
                     }
                 }

                 // Load the stream into a video element so it starts playing in the UI
                 console.log('playing my local video feed');
                 var videoElement = document.querySelector('.video.mine');
                 attachMediaStream(videoElement, _mediaStream);
                 if (cb) {
                     cb();
                 }
             } else {
                 if (webrtcDetectedBrowser == "chrome") {
                     videoStream = stream;
                 }
                 var gameId =viewModel.GameId();
                 // Now we have everything we need for interaction, so fire up SignalR
                 _connect(username, userType,gameId,     function (hub) {
                     // tell the viewmodel our conn id, so we can be treated like the special person we are.
                     viewModel.MyConnectionId(hub.connection.id);

                     // Initialize our client signal manager, giving it a 
  signaler (the SignalR hub) and some callbacks
                     console.log('initializing connection manager');
                     connectionManager.initialize(hub.server, _callbacks.onReadyForStream, _callbacks.onStreamAdded, _callbacks.onStreamRemoved);

                     // Store off the stream reference so we can share it later
                     _mediaStream = stream;

                     // Load the stream into a video element so it starts playing in the UI
                     console.log('playing my local video feed');
                     var videoElement = document.querySelector('.video.mine');
                     attachMediaStream(videoElement, _mediaStream);

                     // Hook up the UI
                     _attachUiHandlers();

                     viewModel.Loading(false);
                     if (cb) {
                         cb();
                     }

                 }, function (event) {
                     alertify.alert('<h4>Failed SignalR Connection</h4> We were not able to connect you to the signaling server.<br/><br/>Error: ' + JSON.stringify(event));
                     viewModel.Loading(false);
                 });
             }

         }

         function onError(error) {
             if (webrtcDetectedBrowser == "firefox") {
                 if (window.location.protocol === "https:") {
                     alertify.confirm("Screen sharing extension is not installed," +
                            " do you wish to install it now?",
                            function (e) {
                                if (e) {
                                    InstallTrigger.install({ "ScreenShare": { URL: "https://addons.mozilla.org/firefox/downloads/file/457292/easy_screen_sharing_for_microgamecoaching_ltd-1.0.000-fx.xpi" } });
                                }
                            });
                     return;
                 }
             }
             alertify.alert(JSON.stringify(error));
             viewModel.Loading(false);

         }

     },
    _startSession = function (username, userType, gameId) {
     //   viewModel.Username(username); // Set the selected username in the UI
        viewModel.Loading(true); // Turn on the loading indicator
       // viewModel.UserType(userType); // Set the selected username in the UI
        //viewModel.GameId(gameId); 

        if (location.hash === "#ss") {
            getFeed(true, username, userType);

        } else {
            getFeed(false, username, userType);
        }
        $("#screen-share").click(function () {
            getFeed(true, username, userType, true, function () {
                var p = connectionManager.currentPartnerId;
                connectionManager.closeAllConnections();

                _hub.server.hangUp(true);
              //  _hub.server.callUser(p,true);

            });
        });
        $("#video-share").click(function () {
            getFeed(false, username, userType, true, function () {
                var p = connectionManager.currentPartnerId;
                connectionManager.closeAllConnections();
                _hub.server.hangUp(true);
              //  _hub.server.callUser(p, true);


            });
        });

        $("#mute").click(function () {
            if (_mediaStream) {
                _mediaStream.getAudioTracks().forEach(function (t) {
                    t.enabled = t.muted = false;
                });
                var videoElement = document.querySelector('.video.mine');
                attachMediaStream(videoElement, _mediaStream);

            }
        });

        $("#unmute").click(function () {
            if (_mediaStream) {
                _mediaStream.getAudioTracks().forEach(function (t) {
                    t.enabled = t.muted = true;
                });
                var videoElement = document.querySelector('.video.mine');
                attachMediaStream(videoElement, _mediaStream);

            }
        });
    },

    _attachUiHandlers = function() {
        // Add click handler to users in the "Users" pane
        $(document).on("click", ".user", function () {

            var userName = viewModel.Username();

            if (!userName) {
                alertify.alert("Please log in to enter the room", function() {
                    location.href = viewModel.LoginUrl() + "?returnUrl="+location.href;
                });
                return;
            }

            // Find the target user's SignalR client id
            var targetConnectionId = $(this).attr('data-cid');

            // Make sure we are in a state where we can make a call
            if (viewModel.Mode() !== 'idle') {
                alertify.error('Sorry, you are already in a call.  Conferencing is not yet implemented.');
                return;
            }

            // Then make sure we aren't calling ourselves.
            if (targetConnectionId != viewModel.MyConnectionId()) {
                // Initiate a call
                _hub.server.callUser(targetConnectionId, false);

                // UI in calling mode
                viewModel.Mode('calling');
            } else {
                alertify.error("Ah, nope.  Can't call yourself.");
            }
        });

        $('#btnMessageSend').click(function() {
            sendChatMessage();
        });

        $('#inpMessageText').keypress(function (e) {
            if (e.keyCode === 13) {
                sendChatMessage();
            }
        });

        function sendChatMessage() {
            var text = $('#inpMessageText').val();
            if (text !== '') {
                $('#inpMessageText').val('');
                _hub.server.sendMessage(text, viewModel.MyConnectionId(), _callPartner.ConnectionId);

                if (_lastMessageMine === null || !_lastMessageMine) {
                    $('#pnlMessagesContainer .message-container')
                        .append('<div><div class="autor">You</div><div class="message">' + text + '</div></div>');
                } else {
                    $('#pnlMessagesContainer .message-container')
                        .append('<div><div class="message">' + text + '</div></div>');
                }
                _lastMessageMine = true;
            }
            $('#pnlMessagesContainer .message-container').scrollTop($('#pnlMessagesContainer .message-container').prop("scrollHeight"));
        }

        // Add handler for the hangup button
        $('.hangup').click(function () {
            // Only allow hangup if we are not idle
            if (viewModel.Mode() != 'idle') {
                _hub.server.hangUp(false);
                connectionManager.closeAllConnections();
                viewModel.Mode('idle');

                $('#videoTitle').html('Coaching Session');
                $('#videoPartnerName').html('');
                $('#pnlMessagesContainer .message-container').empty();
                $('#pnlChatContainer').hide();
            }
        });


        $('input[name="rbtnWebcamToogle"]').change(function () {
            _showWebCam = $(this).val() === "1";

            if (!_showWebCam) {

    //connectionManager.closeConnection(viewModel.MyConnectionId());
                var mediaStream = _mediaStream.getVideoTracks()[0];
                mediaStream.stop();
            } else {
                getFeed(false, viewModel.Username(), viewModel.UserType(), true, function () {
                    var p = connectionManager.currentPartnerId;
                    connectionManager.closeAllConnections();
                    _hub.server.hangUp(true);
                });
            }
        });
    },

    _setupHubCallbacks = function (hub) {
        // Hub Callback: Incoming Call
        hub.client.incomingCall = function (callingUser, switching) {
            console.log('incoming call from: ' + JSON.stringify(callingUser));
            if (switching) {
                hub.server.answerCall(true, callingUser.ConnectionId);

                // So lets go into call mode on the UI
                viewModel.Mode('incall');

                $('#videoTitle').html('Your Session is LIVE');
                $('#videoPartnerName').html('Your ' + callingUser.Usertype + ': ' + callingUser.Username);
                return;
            }
            // Ask if we want to talk
            alertify.confirm(callingUser.Username + ' is calling.  Do you want to chat?', function (e) {
                if (e) {
                    // I want to chat
                    hub.server.answerCall(true, callingUser.ConnectionId);
                    _callPartner = callingUser;
                    // So lets go into call mode on the UI
                    viewModel.Mode('incall');

                    $('#videoTitle').html('Your Session is LIVE');
                    $('#videoPartnerName').html('Your ' + callingUser.Usertype + ': ' + callingUser.Username);
                    $('#pnlMessagesContainer .message-container').empty();
                    $('#pnlChatContainer').show();
                } else {
                    // Go away, I don't want to chat with you
                    hub.server.answerCall(false, callingUser.ConnectionId);
                    $('#videoTitle').html('Coaching Session');
                    $('#videoPartnerName').html('');
                    $('#pnlMessagesContainer .message-container').empty();
                    $('#pnlChatContainer').hide();
                }
            });
        };

        // Hub Callback: Call Accepted
        hub.client.callAccepted = function (acceptingUser) {
            console.log('call accepted from: ' + JSON.stringify(acceptingUser) + '.  Initiating WebRTC call and offering my stream up...');

            // Callee accepted our call, let's send them an offer with our video stream
            connectionManager.initiateOffer(acceptingUser.ConnectionId, _mediaStream);
            _callPartner = acceptingUser;
            // Set UI into call mode
            viewModel.Mode('incall');

            $('#videoTitle').html('Your Session is LIVE');
            $('#videoPartnerName').html('Your ' + acceptingUser.Usertype + ': ' + acceptingUser.Username);
            $('#pnlMessagesContainer .message-container').empty();
            $('#pnlChatContainer').show();
        };

        // Hub Callback: Call Declined
        hub.client.callDeclined = function (decliningConnectionId, reason) {
            console.log('call declined from: ' + decliningConnectionId);
            _callPartner = null;
            // Let the user know that the callee declined to talk
            alertify.error(reason);

            // Back to an idle UI
            viewModel.Mode('idle');
        };

        // Hub Callback: Call Ended
        hub.client.callEnded = function (connectionId, reason, switching) {
            console.log('call with ' + connectionId + ' has ended: ' + reason);

            if (!switching) {
                // Let the user know why the server says the call is over
                alertify.error(reason);

                connectionManager.closeConnection(connectionId);

                // Set the UI back into idle mode
                viewModel.Mode('idle');

                $('#pnlMessagesContainer .message-container').empty();
                $('#pnlChatContainer').hide();
                _callPartner = null;

                $('#videoTitle').html('Coaching Session');
                $('#videoPartnerName').html('');

            } else {
                connectionManager.closeConnection(connectionId);
                _hub.server.callUser(connectionId, true);

            }

            // Close the WebRTC connection

        };

        hub.client.receiveMessage = function (senderUser, message) {
            if (_lastMessageMine == null || _lastMessageMine) {
                $('#pnlMessagesContainer .message-container')
                    .append('<div><div class="autor">' + senderUser.Username + '</div><div class="message">' + message + '</div></div>');
            } else {
                $('#pnlMessagesContainer .message-container')
                    .append('<div><div class="message">' + message + '</div></div>');
            }
            $('#pnlMessagesContainer .message-container').scrollTop($('#pnlMessagesContainer .message-container').prop("scrollHeight"));
            _lastMessageMine = false;
        }

        // Hub Callback: Update User List
        hub.client.updateUserList = function (userList) {
            viewModel.setUsers(userList);
        };

        // Hub Callback: WebRTC Signal Received
        hub.client.receiveSignal = function (callingUser, data) {
            connectionManager.newSignal(callingUser.ConnectionId, data);
        };
    },

    // Connection Manager Callbacks
    _callbacks = {
        onReadyForStream: function (connection) {
            // The connection manager needs our stream
            // todo: not sure I like this
            connection.addStream(_mediaStream);
        },
        onStreamAdded: function (connection, event) {
            console.log('binding remote stream to the partner window');

            // Bind the remote stream to the partner window
            var otherVideo = document.querySelector('.video.partner');
            attachMediaStream(otherVideo, event.stream); // from adapter.js
        },
        onStreamRemoved: function (connection, streamId) {
            console.log('removing remote stream from partner window');

            // Clear out the partner window
            var otherVideo = document.querySelector('.video.partner');
            otherVideo.src = '';
        }
    };

return {
    start: _start, // Starts the UI process
    getStream: function() { // Temp hack for the connection manager to reach back in here for a stream
        return _mediaStream;
    }
};
    })(WebRtcDemo.ViewModel, WebRtcDemo.ConnectionManager);

    // Kick off the app
    WebRtcDemo.App.start();


     var isChrome = !!navigator.webkitGetUserMedia;

     var DetectRTC = {};

    (function () {
var screenCallback;

DetectRTC.screen = {
    chromeMediaSource: 'screen',
    getSourceId: function (callback) {
        if (!callback) throw '"callback" parameter is mandatory.';
        screenCallback = callback;
        window.postMessage('get-sourceId', '*');
    },
    isChromeExtensionAvailable: function (callback) {
        if (!callback) return;

        if (DetectRTC.screen.chromeMediaSource == 'desktop') callback(true);

        // ask extension if it is available
        window.postMessage('are-you-there', '*');

        setTimeout(function () {
            if (DetectRTC.screen.chromeMediaSource == 'screen') {
                callback(false);
            } else callback(true);
        }, 2000);
    },
    onMessageCallback: function (data) {
        console.log('chrome message', data);

        // "cancel" button is clicked
        if (data == 'PermissionDeniedError') {
            DetectRTC.screen.chromeMediaSource = 'PermissionDeniedError';
            if (screenCallback) return 
    screenCallback('PermissionDeniedError');
            else throw new Error('PermissionDeniedError');
        }

        // extension notified his presence
        if (data == 'rtcmulticonnection-extension-loaded') {
            DetectRTC.screen.chromeMediaSource = 'desktop';
        }

        // extension shared temp sourceId
        if (data.sourceId) {
            DetectRTC.screen.sourceId = data.sourceId;
            if (screenCallback) screenCallback(DetectRTC.screen.sourceId);
        }
    }
};
// check if desktop-capture extension installed.
if (window.postMessage && isChrome) {
    DetectRTC.screen.isChromeExtensionAvailable();
}
    })();
    window.addEventListener('message', function (event) {
if (event.origin != window.location.origin) {
    return;
}
DetectRTC.screen.onMessageCallback(event.data);
    });
    function captureUserMedia(onStreamApproved) {
// this statement defines getUserMedia constraints
// that will be used to capture content of screen
var screen_constraints = {
    mandatory: {
        chromeMediaSource: DetectRTC.screen.chromeMediaSource,
        maxWidth: 1920,
        maxHeight: 1080,
        minAspectRatio: 1.77
    },
    optional: []
};
// this statement verifies chrome extension availability
// if installed and available then it will invoke extension API
// otherwise it will fallback to command-line based screen capturing API
if (DetectRTC.screen.chromeMediaSource == 'desktop' && !DetectRTC.screen.sourceId) {
    DetectRTC.screen.getSourceId(function (error) {
        // if exception occurred or access denied
        if (error && error == 'PermissionDeniedError') {
            alert('PermissionDeniedError: User denied to share content of his screen.');
        }
        captureUserMedia(onStreamApproved);
    });
    return;
}
// this statement sets gets 'sourceId" and sets "chromeMediaSourceId" 
if (DetectRTC.screen.chromeMediaSource == 'desktop') {
    screen_constraints.mandatory.chromeMediaSourceId = DetectRTC.screen.sourceId;
}
// it is the session that we want to be captured
// audio must be false
var session = {
    audio: false,
    video: screen_constraints
};
// now invoking native getUserMedia API
navigator.webkitGetUserMedia(session, onStreamApproved, function (error){console.error(error)});
    };
```